# Poor performance for traversing all the documents from mongodb using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I store the system log in mongodb with building index according to 'time' field. There are about 190k logs in mongodb now.
When I try to get all logs using *DBCollection.find()* method in Java, it spends almost 10 seconds for traversing all the documents in the collection. I think there might be something I have missed that cause the poor performance?

Here is the code I used:

```
mongo = new Mongo();
DB db = mongo.getDB("Log");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("SystemLog");
int count = 0;

long findStart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

// Sort by time.
BasicDBObject queryObj = new BasicDBObject();
queryObj.put("time", -1);

DBCursor cursor = coll.find().sort(queryObj);
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject obj = cursor.next();
    // Do something
    ++count;
}
long findEnd = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println("Time for traversing all system logs (" + count + "):\t" + (findEnd-findStart) + "ms.");
```

And the printed result is:

```
Time for traversing all system log (194309):    10496ms.
```

I have tried it several times. It seems no difference between running one time or multiple times. Though I have also tried to remove *sort()* and just find all the logs out from mongodb. It takes about 6 seconds for traversing all the documents. The time is still kind of unacceptable for my requirement. Is there any implementation tips that can speed up the traversing work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to traverse all documents ? In the code above it looks like you are just bringing into memory each object, one by one.

1. The index on 'time' field should be constructed as 'descending' since you are sorting like that.
2. If the index is compound (has more fields in the index, not just 'time') make sure you also add an index just with 'time'. Also, when you will add a filter to that query, make sure the 'time' field is added last in the index and descending.
3. The performance is not that bad, considering you are reading 190k objects one by one.

(please note that my experience with mongodb does Not involve working with the Java driver)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sugguestions. Yes, I need to traverse all documents. Actually what I need to do is to export all the logs from mongodb to a file, and thus I have to get the documents one by one into memory (and write them to a text file with fixed format). However, I hope this work could be done in no more than 5 seconds since after generating the log file, users have to wait another few seconds for downloading the log file.

Comment: Make sure the index for the time descending is there. Also, i would try to get the objects a few k at once. Have limit and skip on the query (Java driver should hande this) and get the objects in chunks. Look in the mongo profiler to see what is going on there. Best scenario you will see a cursor that each time returns large chunks of objects in a full indexed way.